# Jsp/ Servlet page examle

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm new to jsp/servlets and trying to figure out what is the correct way to write a jsp page. I have read another thread here saying that scriplets is not such a good technique and should be avoided.
I'm trying to find a complete example of replacing a jsp with a servlet, because I have read some other answers and I'm little confused.

Actually, in my home page I have a link tag(Products) redirecting to product.jsp, where a scriplet is used to show all products(name, model, price, manufacturer) from my database.

If I want to convert this to servlet how can I do it?
I'm aware of making a class that extends HttpServlet and use doGet.
Something like:

```
public class IndexController extends HttpServlet {
    ListProducts listProducts;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.setAttribute("products", listProducts.getproducts());
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }

}
```

Other than that, I need a class `ListProducts` that makes the database connection and a function `getProducts` that returns a list of products inside?
Or am I missing something?
And what if I want to pass parameters from url inside servlet to get a specific product?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Thank you both for the reply. I was able to successfully create my servlet, which forwards to a products.jsp page. Is it possible to include products.jsp to another page as well? If I do include page "ProductsServlet" all html code converts to products.jsp html and of course include file "products.jsp" shows no products of course.

Answer (score 0):

JSP Should only have the presentation logic, where we display /collect information from user. The JSP should pass these information to a Servlet where we have our business logic and send back a response which again displayed in a JSP or HTML page.

*(Ideally the servlet should call a service class which inturns calls a DAO for any DB interaction)*

Please go through basics of Servlets JSP I recommend **Head First JSP/Servlets** with the strong  basics you can code good applications.

In response to your edit:

In JSP use JSTL tags to display data. Make a **ProductService** and **ProductDao** class.
ProductDao will interact with DB with methods like getProducts(String productId) and deleteProduct(id) etc.

Have similar method in ProductService with all business logic here.

And from your Servlets  doGet or doPost call the service class method which should call your Dao methods.

If you are adding/editing data to application/Database use a POST else if you are requesting existing data use get.

**And do checkout [these](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html) tutorials.**

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is more like a (Model View Controller) **MVC** architecture that you are heading to, which is a good thing.

You have already created the Servlet (controler).

Now you need a class called **ListProducts** which acts as the **Model**.

And the view will be the jsp where you want to show the results.

The **ListProducts** class will have a list (may be an `ArrayList`) to hold the list of products and one method **getProducts** to return the list.

This **ListProducts** class can use another class which can create a database connection and make queries. The **ListProducts** class should call one of the methods of the class which crreates the **DB Connection** and gets the list of products and updates itself.

After this Your servlets can get this list from the **ListProducts** calss and display it on some jsp.

Example:

```
class HandleDBConnections{

    ArrayList listOfProducts;

   makeQuery(String param);

   ArrayList getList(String yourParameterForSpecificProduct) {
       listOfProducts = makeQuery(yourParameterForSpecificProduct);
       return this.listOfProducts;
   }
}


class ListProducts {
    ArrayList list;
    getProducts() {
        // get list from DB handlers above

        return this.list; // return the list
    }
}
```

Now you can also pass some parameter from the servlet to get specific products. The `yourParameterForSpecificProduct` is for the same purpose. If you don't want to pass the parameter you can have one more method with same name without parameter.